# Generic Methods and Type Inferencing in Java

Tags: java, generics, type-inference

Given the following not-very-useful code:

```java
package com.something;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

//Not a generic class!
public class Test {

  public <T> void plain(T param1, T param2) {}
  public <T> void fancy(T param1, Collection<T> param2) {}

  public void testMethod() {

    //No error
    fancy("", new ArrayList<String>());

    //Compiler error here!
    fancy("", new ArrayList<Integer>());

    //No error
    plain("", new ArrayList<Integer>());

  }

}
```

(Please correct my understanding if it's wrong!)

The 2nd call to `fancy()` is a compiler error because Java can't infer any common type between the two arguments (can't infer `Object` since the second parameter must be a `Collection`.)

The call to `plain()` is *not* a compiler error because Java infers the common type of `Object` between the two arguments.

I recently came across code that had a method signature similar to `plain()`.

My question is this:

**Is `plain()`'s signature useful for anything?**

Perhaps the person who wrote that code thought that `plain()`'s signature would enforce that both parameters have the same type at compile time, which is obviously not the case.

Is there any difference from or benefit to writing a method with a signature like `plain()` rather than just defining both parameters to be `Object`s?

Comment: Real generic programming is merely existing in Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the compiler does not infer the generic type one might intend, it *will* enforce type constraints that are explicitly specified. The following invocation results in a type error.

```
this.<String>plain("", new ArrayList<Integer>()); /* Compiler error. */
```

> The parameterized method <String>plain(String, String) of type Test is not applicable for the arguments (String, ArrayList<Integer>)

Comment: Makes sense! This is the missing piece I was after. Thank you!

Comment: Ok; We have to call on className instead of this

Answer (score 3):

I guess you could say it serves as some sort of documentation, so that the user knows that you expect both arguments to be of the same type. Of course, *any* two objects are of the same type to some degree (they're all `Object`), so it's a meaningless statement.

Long story short, it's a useless signature.

Of course, if `plain` returned a type `T`, that'd be a different story.

Comment: Just curious; Could you please elaborate that story.

Comment: @KanagaveluSugumar What part specific would you like elaboration on?

Comment: if plain returned a type T, what is the impact? and if it is not.

Comment: @KanagaveluSugumar If plain returned a `T`, then in java 7 the `T`'s type would be inferred _only_ from the argument, and the return value would have to be of the same time. In java 8, I think this is relaxed a bit. But if it doesn't return the type, and it's just used as the argument types, then Java will try to infer any type so long as that type is a superclass of both arguments. Since all classes extend Object, that inference is guaranteed to work, but it's not guaranteed to give you anything meaningful. The intent is probably "two args of the same type", but that's not what you'll get.

Answer (score 1):

> The 2nd call to fancy() is a compiler error because Java can't infer
>   any common type between the two arguments (can't infer Object since
>   the second parameter must be a Collection.)

Well, I am not sure this is the reason, I would say the reason is that the generic type `T` in `Collection<T>` is an invariant whose value determines the type of the first parameter `T`.

For instance, this is valid:

```
fancy("", new ArrayList<CharSequence>()); //compiles Ok
```

Because all `String` are `CharSequences`. It is expected that the first parameter is a `CharSequence` once the type is inferred from `ArraysList<CharSequence>`.

However, this is not valid:

```
fancy((CharSequence)"", new ArrayList<String>()); //compiler error
```

Because it is expected the type of the first parameter be `String`, and we cannot ensure that all `CharSequences` are, in fact, of type `String`, right?

So, AFAIK, the reason the types are not compatible is due to the nature of generics in this case, and not to the fact that the second type is a `Collection`.

Comment: Makes sense. This actually occurred to me as well, but I didn't go far enough to produce something similar to the "valid" example you pointed out. Thanks very much for correcting my understanding!